# How can I get last 50 documents in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, lastinsertid

**How can I get last 50 documents in mongoDB?**

I have a collection which is made by

```
db.createCollection("collection",{capped:true, size:300000});
```

from this "collection"

I would like to have last 50 documents instead of get first 50 documents.

I know that I can get first 50 documents by using

```
db.collection.find().limit(50);
```

But how can I get last 50 documents?

**Is this can be done simply with MongoDB API or should I implement this with programming?**

Comment: There is another related question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 23):

this should do the thing:

```
db.collection.find().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

The last N added records, from less recent to most recent, can be seen with this query:

```
db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - N)
```

In your case 50

```
db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the last 50 documents from mongo collection, so this is the query

```
db.collection('collectionName').find().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(50);

// sort({$natural: -1}) for the last fields (desecnding)
// limit(50) because you need only 50 fields
```