# Get latest 5 data from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, database

Im working with node.js express and using MongoDB, I have a list of data with username and id. If i want to console.log 5 lastest data that inserted to the database, how would you do it? Any ideas?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records

Comment: `db.foo.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ObjectID, which is the default value of the _id field, contains a timestamp. You can sort() your data by ObjectID to get the latest documents inserted into the database.

If you're using a different _id, you'll need to make sure that you store a timestamp somewhere in your documents.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D