# Mongo remove last documents

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know how to delete, for example, the last 100 documents inserted in my collection.

How is it possible from the shell?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use the `_id` to sort on last inserted, as outlined in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records):

```
db.coll.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(100);
```

It [looks like](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/204) using limit on the standard mongo remove operation isn't supported though, so you might use something like this to delete the 100 documents:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
    db.coll.findAndModify({query :{}, sort: {"_id" : -1}, remove:true})
}
```

See the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) for more on `findAndModify`.

Comment: there are some problems with this answer.  1) you are assuming his _id values are monotonically increasing. but if they are 2) you are suggesting running a loop 100 times instead of just doing a single remove statement db.coll.remove({_id:{$gte:<value-of-100th-id>}

Comment: The answer I pointed to suggests that the _id will return the most recent items: "If you use the auto created _id field it has a date embedded in it ... so you can use that to order by".  Would that not be accurate under some circumstances (e.g. when db is sharded)?  

Regardless, I'd certainly agree that the single call would be more efficient-- thanks!

Comment: they point out *if* you use _id - but don't forget that people can provide their own _id value which might be distributed differently and also _id is generated on the client - if they have multiple clients some of their clocks *might* be off(!)