# limit() and sort() order pymongo and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Despite reading peoples answers stating that the sort is done first, evidence shows something different that the limit is done before the sort. Is there a way to force sort always first?

```
views = mongo.db.view_logging.find().sort([('count', 1)]).limit(10)
```

Whether I use `.sort().limit()` or `.limit().sort()`, the limit takes precedence. I wonder if this is something to do with `pymongo`...

Comment: What are your PyMongo and MongoDB versions?

Comment: Can you repo it on a small dataset `{_id:1}, {_id:2}` etc. and give us your exact code and outputs?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods), **regardless of which goes first in your chain of commands, `sort()` would be always applied before the `limit()`.**

You can also study the [`.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) results of your query and look at the execution stages - you will find that the sorting input stage examines all of the filtered (in your case all documents in the collection) and then the limit is applied.

---

Let's go through an example.

Imagine there is a `foo` database with a `test` collection having 6 documents:

```
>>> col = db.foo.test
>>> for doc in col.find():
...     print(doc)
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:12:00', '_id': ObjectId('56f9716ce4b05e6b92be87f2'), 'value': 90}
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:13:00', '_id': ObjectId('56f971a3e4b05e6b92be87fc'), 'value': 82}
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:14:00', '_id': ObjectId('56f971afe4b05e6b92be87fd'), 'value': 75}
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:15:00', '_id': ObjectId('56f971b7e4b05e6b92be87ff'), 'value': 72}
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:16:00', '_id': ObjectId('56f971c0e4b05e6b92be8803'), 'value': 81}
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:17:00', '_id': ObjectId('56f971c8e4b05e6b92be8806'), 'value': 90}
```

Now, let's execute queries with different order of `sort()` and `limit()` and check the results and the explain plan.

Sort and then limit:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> cursor = col.find().sort([('time', 1)]).limit(3)  
>>> sort_limit_plan = cursor.explain()
>>> pprint(sort_limit_plan)
{u'executionStats': {u'allPlansExecution': [],
                     u'executionStages': {u'advanced': 3,
                                          u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0,
                                          u'inputStage': {u'advanced': 6,
                                                          u'direction': u'forward',
                                                          u'docsExamined': 6,
                                                          u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0,
                                                          u'filter': {u'$and': []},
                                                          u'invalidates': 0,
                                                          u'isEOF': 1,
                                                          u'nReturned': 6,
                                                          u'needFetch': 0,
                                                          u'needTime': 1,
                                                          u'restoreState': 0,
                                                          u'saveState': 0,
                                                          u'stage': u'COLLSCAN',
                                                          u'works': 8},
                                          u'invalidates': 0,
                                          u'isEOF': 1,
                                          u'limitAmount': 3,
                                          u'memLimit': 33554432,
                                          u'memUsage': 213,
                                          u'nReturned': 3,
                                          u'needFetch': 0,
                                          u'needTime': 8,
                                          u'restoreState': 0,
                                          u'saveState': 0,
                                          u'sortPattern': {u'time': 1},
                                          u'stage': u'SORT',
                                          u'works': 13},
                     u'executionSuccess': True,
                     u'executionTimeMillis': 0,
                     u'nReturned': 3,
                     u'totalDocsExamined': 6,
                     u'totalKeysExamined': 0},
 u'queryPlanner': {u'indexFilterSet': False,
                   u'namespace': u'foo.test',
                   u'parsedQuery': {u'$and': []},
                   u'plannerVersion': 1,
                   u'rejectedPlans': [],
                   u'winningPlan': {u'inputStage': {u'direction': u'forward',
                                                    u'filter': {u'$and': []},
                                                    u'stage': u'COLLSCAN'},
                                    u'limitAmount': 3,
                                    u'sortPattern': {u'time': 1},
                                    u'stage': u'SORT'}},
 u'serverInfo': {u'gitVersion': u'6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd',
                 u'host': u'h008742.mongolab.com',
                 u'port': 53439,
                 u'version': u'3.0.7'}}
```

Limit and then sort:

```
>>> cursor = col.find().limit(3).sort([('time', 1)])
>>> limit_sort_plan = cursor.explain()
>>> pprint(limit_sort_plan)
{u'executionStats': {u'allPlansExecution': [],
                     u'executionStages': {u'advanced': 3,
                                          u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0,
                                          u'inputStage': {u'advanced': 6,
                                                          u'direction': u'forward',
                                                          u'docsExamined': 6,
                                                          u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0,
                                                          u'filter': {u'$and': []},
                                                          u'invalidates': 0,
                                                          u'isEOF': 1,
                                                          u'nReturned': 6,
                                                          u'needFetch': 0,
                                                          u'needTime': 1,
                                                          u'restoreState': 0,
                                                          u'saveState': 0,
                                                          u'stage': u'COLLSCAN',
                                                          u'works': 8},
                                          u'invalidates': 0,
                                          u'isEOF': 1,
                                          u'limitAmount': 3,
                                          u'memLimit': 33554432,
                                          u'memUsage': 213,
                                          u'nReturned': 3,
                                          u'needFetch': 0,
                                          u'needTime': 8,
                                          u'restoreState': 0,
                                          u'saveState': 0,
                                          u'sortPattern': {u'time': 1},
                                          u'stage': u'SORT',
                                          u'works': 13},
                     u'executionSuccess': True,
                     u'executionTimeMillis': 0,
                     u'nReturned': 3,
                     u'totalDocsExamined': 6,
                     u'totalKeysExamined': 0},
 u'queryPlanner': {u'indexFilterSet': False,
                   u'namespace': u'foo.test',
                   u'parsedQuery': {u'$and': []},
                   u'plannerVersion': 1,
                   u'rejectedPlans': [],
                   u'winningPlan': {u'inputStage': {u'direction': u'forward',
                                                    u'filter': {u'$and': []},
                                                    u'stage': u'COLLSCAN'},
                                    u'limitAmount': 3,
                                    u'sortPattern': {u'time': 1},
                                    u'stage': u'SORT'}},
 u'serverInfo': {u'gitVersion': u'6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd',
                 u'host': u'h008742.mongolab.com',
                 u'port': 53439,
                 u'version': u'3.0.7'}}
```

As you can see, in both cases the sort is applied first and affects all the 6 documents and then the limit limits the results to 3.

And, the **execution plans are exactly the same**:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy  # just in case
>>> cursor = col.find().sort([('time', 1)]).limit(3)
>>> sort_limit_plan = deepcopy(cursor.explain())
>>> cursor = col.find().limit(3).sort([('time', 1)])
>>> limit_sort_plan = deepcopy(cursor.explain())
>>> sort_limit_plan == limit_sort_plan
True
```

Also see:

- [How do you tell Mongo to sort a collection before limiting the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509025/how-do-you-tell-mongo-to-sort-a-collection-before-limiting-the-results)

Answer (score 4):

The mongodb documentation states that the `skip()` method controls the starting point of the results set, followed by `sort()` and ends with the `limit()` method.

This is regardless the order of your code. The reason is that mongo gets all the methods for the query, then it orders the skip-sort-limit methods in that exact order, and then runs the query.

Answer (score 3):

Logically it should be whatever comes first in pipeline, But MongoDB always sort first before limit.

In my test Sort operation does takes precedence regardless of if it's coming before skip or after. However, it appears to be very strange behavior to me.

My sample dataset is:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef81"), 
        "number" : 48.98052410874508
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef82"), 
        "number" : 50.98747461471063
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef83"), 
        "number" : 81.32911244349772
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef84"), 
        "number" : 87.95549919039071
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef85"), 
        "number" : 81.63582683594402
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef86"), 
        "number" : 43.25696270026136
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef87"), 
        "number" : 88.22046335409453
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef88"), 
        "number" : 64.00556739160076
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef89"), 
        "number" : 16.09353150244296
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f845fea524b4d098e0ef8a"), 
        "number" : 17.46667776660574
    }
]
```

Python test code:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
database = client.get_database("test")
collection = database.get_collection("collection")

print("----------------[limit -> sort]--------------------------")
result = collection.find().limit(5).sort([("number", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
for r in result:
    print(r)

print("----------------[sort -> limit]--------------------------")
result = collection.find().sort([("number", pymongo.ASCENDING)]).limit(5)
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Result:

```
----------------[limit -> sort]--------------------------
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef89'), u'number': 16.09353150244296}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef8a'), u'number': 17.46667776660574}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef86'), u'number': 43.25696270026136}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef81'), u'number': 48.98052410874508}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef82'), u'number': 50.98747461471063}
----------------[sort -> limit]--------------------------
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef89'), u'number': 16.09353150244296}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef8a'), u'number': 17.46667776660574}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef86'), u'number': 43.25696270026136}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef81'), u'number': 48.98052410874508}
{u'_id': ObjectId('56f845fea524b4d098e0ef82'), u'number': 50.98747461471063}
```

Comment: The order there, should sort first, unless I'm mistaken, but it appears that it limits firsts. No matter the order of sort or limit, limit occurs on the recordset first.

Comment: @Navonod from my experience, it appears that Sort operation is taking precedence. see result

Comment: Sadly limit is always taking precedence in my usage.

Comment: well, this is strange. try updating your MongoDB driver

Comment: See updated post along with test code and result. I don't see any difference from my previous post. `sort` is always taking precedence.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect, you're passing wrong key in sort parameter. something like "$key_name" instead of just "key_name"

refer [How do you tell Mongo to sort a collection before limiting the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509025/how-do-you-tell-mongo-to-sort-a-collection-before-limiting-the-results)[solution for same problem as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509025/how-do-you-tell-mongo-to-sort-a-collection-before-limiting-the-results)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this does:

```
last5 = db.collection.find(   {'key': "YOURKEY"},   sort=[( '_id', pymongo.DESCENDING )] ).limit(5)
```

with the limit outside and the sort inside of the find argument.