# How can I get the latest documents by publication date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongodb, documents have a property like this: `dateOfPublication: 2021-04-09T21:25:05.612+00:00`.

How can I get, say, the first 3 posts by time?

Comment: run a query sorted by dateOfPublication ascending then limit the results to 3. Docs can be a good starting place.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @turivishal, that's the problem: I can't even imagine how this can be done

Comment: no one  can imagine, you need to search in google or stack overflow, see i found in  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509025/how-do-you-tell-mongo-to-sort-a-collection-before-limiting-the-results) and you have to follow mongodb docs you will easily get in google just type in *mongodb find with sort and limit*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). You need two staged:

1. Sort your documents with [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)
2. Limit your results to let's say
   3 with [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

Example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {'dateOfPublication': 1}},
  {$limit: 3}
])
```