# Select last N records from MongoDB using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

*Note: I have seen the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records) and tried answers from it with no luck.*

I have a collection in MongoDB:

```
{ _id: 1, category_id: 1, time_added: 1234567890, name: "abc" }
```

I need to find last 10 entries from `category_id` equal to **10**. Sound simple?

```
collection.find({ 'category_id': 10 }, {}, { _id: -1, limit : 10}, function (e, d) {});
```

But running this gives me **first** 10 records instead of last 10. Looks like driver has priority to "limit" and not "sorting"... I also tries with `$natural` and sorting on `time_added`. Whenever I run the same query from command line - I get what I need. Here is what I type into command line:

```
collection.find({ 'category_id': 10 }).sort({_id: -1}).limit(10)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative way to do this with node.js?

Comment: Are you using the [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver?  It has support for a chainable `sort` method, allowing you to issue a query to the driver very much like your command line.

Comment: @RayToal Yes. I am using that driver. Where do I put the callback? In limit as the last parameter? What if I remove .limit(), can I place callback in any function as a last parameter? P.S. I tried and it worked. Add that as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Xeos - you can add an answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out node.js accepts function calls in the same way the command line interface does. Every function has last optional argument as callback function. So this code runs and returns the correct results:

```
collection.find({ 'category_id': 10 }).sort({_id: -1}).limit(10, function (e, d) {})
```

Comment: @G.Ghez It's not random at all. Here is the description of the ObjectId http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/ When I sort by ObjectId, I am essentially sorting it by timestamp. Further, if there were multiple inserts in one second, then there is the counter. This works pretty well for one-server setup. It would not work with multiple servers, as machine and process IDs would mess with the chronological ordering.

Comment: Thank you for sharing then ^^