# get last 30 records from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to select the last 30 or any amount of records inserted into a mongoDB currently using find with all parameters emitted.

```
db.tweets.find({}, function(err, docs){
    response.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
});
```

Im not sure what needs to go in the curly brackets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20307485/2197026

i think this post will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of find() for [mongo-native](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) (same for mongoskin) is:

```
find(query[, options], callback)
```

or

```
find(query[, options]).toArray(callback)
```

1st argument is search criteria, so it can't be in there but the limit can be put in the optional 2nd argument.  Something like this:

```
db.tweets.find({}, {limit: 30}).toArray(function(err, docs){

  response.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
});
```

Update: you can also specify 'sort' to get the LAST 30.  Something like this : {limit: 30, sort:  ["timestamp", "desc"]} (either "desc" or -1, don't remember the syntax) where "timestamp" is the field you want to sort on.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I got confused with having to move the callback!

Comment: Yes it is confusing but conventionally, callback is the last argument, so options argument is squeezed in the middle.  The find() is probably checking if the 2nd argument is an object or a function.  If it's an object, it's treated as options.  If it's a function, it's treated as callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `ObjectId` as the `_id` field for your documents, then sorting in descending order by `_id` will probably give you the right order of documents, starting with the most recently inserted. This is because MongoDB's `ObjectId` contains a timestamp. Note that if you have multiple MongoDB instances running, this will depend on the processes' clocks being well synchronised and I believe the maximum precision is one second. In any case, you can then run something as follows:

```
db.tweets.find({}).sort({ "_id" : -1 }).limit(30, function(err, docs) {
    // Do something here
});
```

However, if you are not using an `ObjectId`, then your documents will need to have a field with a timestamp at the time of creation and you would replace `"_id"` with the name of that field in the code above.

Hope that helps!