# Fetching last record from mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch last record from mongodb database using node.js.
I found some answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294626/select-last-n-records-from-mongodb-using-node-js).
Now i have given query like

```
Videopost.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(10,function(err,docs){}
```

Trying to print docs in console but couldn't get any value in docs.

Comment: How are you printing the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`limit`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) doesn't take a callback parameter, so you have to call `exec` to actually execute the query.

```
Videopost.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(10).exec(function(err,docs) {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is looking for the answer for `node.js`, you can use `findOne()` function. This worked for me:

```
db.collection('collectionName').findOne(
  {},
  { sort: { _id: -1 } },
  (err, data) => {
     console.log(data);
  },
);
```