# Fetching records from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on pagination in node.js application where i am trying to fetch mongodb records using following query.but that gives blank ouput on console []. where as i have more than 15 records in db.

```
Articlepost.find({
  status: true,
  content_category: req.query.type
}).sort({
  "_id": -1
}).skip(4).limit(5).exec(function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(docs);
  }
});
```

As i already asked one question previously [Fetching last record from mongodb using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102382/fetching-last-record-from-mongodb-using-node-js) and @JohnnyHK suggested me to run query using exec. But, the exec seems not working with skip or i might be doing some error.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: In what way is this not working? The callback function supplied to `.exec()` isn't doing anything here as there is no code within it. So how do you know this is not working? Make your exec look like this instead `.exec(function(err,docs) { if (err) throw err; console.log(docs) });`. Then you will at least see something, if only an error. And at least that should give you some insight.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  : Sorry, for minimizing the code i haven't written in post. but actually i tried that and couldn't get any result with blank [].

Comment: Well if it's "blank" then that means at least there is no error, but there is also no document that matches your query conditions. Top new user reasons are 1. Unexpected input. So always `console.log` any `req` params you are receiving, as they probably are not what you think. 2. Wrong collection. You already had data in a collection before using mongoose, but mongoose models use "plural" forms of the model name. So the expected collection in "articleposts" in this case. 3. Wrong database. Your connection URI similarly does not point to the same source you are looking at with the shell.