# mongodb: Retrieve last N records using C language

Tags: c, mongodb

I am running one 'C' application with mongodb. Using mongo shell, I have found a way to [retrieve last N records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records).

But I want to integrate same using C langauge code.

**Edit**
Using `sort()` and `find()` we may get the ascending or descending order data.
One way to limit the output for last N records is to use counter variable with cursor iteration. I am newbie to mongodb and not familiar with BSON objects.

My question is, can I have a similar function for `limit()` in c language drivers of mongodb (instead of using counter kind of thing)?

Comment: FYI, your question is likely to be closed or downvoted because it is unclear if you have done much research. You should start with the MongoDB [C driver tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html#complex-queries) and the [C driver documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/index.html).The tutorial includes an example using `find()` and `sort()` which is the same outcome as the other question you linked. You may also be interested in reading up on the [BCON (BSON C Object Notation)](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/bcon.html) which provides a JSON-like interface for queries.

Comment: @Stennie- I wanted to find similar function of `limit()` in c drivers. Please refer edit. In [tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html#complex-queries), there is no mention about retrieving last N records.

Comment: What version of the MongoDB C driver are you using?  A new version was recently released on Github (Dec, 2013) and there have been some changes between the "legacy" C driver and the new release. FYI, the tutorial and API docs I've linked to are referring to the 0.8.1 "legacy" release which is still the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [MongoDB 0.8.1 driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver-legacy), there is a [`mongo_find()` function](http://api.mongodb.org/c/0.8.1/api/mongo_8h.html#a1889613564f80615e72635307f63592e) to retrieve documents.  This is analogous to the `mongo` shell's `find()` interface with options for `limit` and `skip`:

```
MONGO_EXPORT mongo_cursor* mongo_find   (mongo * conn,
    const char *    ns,
    const bson *    query,
    const bson *    fields,
    int     limit,
    int     skip,
    int     options 
)
```

This isn't currently referenced in the [C driver tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/c/0.8.1/tutorial.html#complex-queries), which uses a lower-level `bson_find()` interface.

Comment: Yes, I am using 0.8.1 drivers. [mongo_find()](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html#a1889613564f80615e72635307f63592e) helped in understanding it. However, I haven't seen this link anywhere while googling.

Comment: Hrm .. the driver API link (http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/) is referenced in many places including the [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/c/) and the [mongodb-user group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mongodb-user) discussion group. It also seems be the top search result for "mongodb c driver api". Is there a missing location or search term you would suggest?

Comment: "MongoDB C Driver Documentation (doxygen generated)" with [this link](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/index.html) on [Tutorial page](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/index.html) will be helpful and / or provide link to doxygen documentation wherever particular function used in tutorial. The doxygen generated documentation link is only available in some google group posts and some stackoverflow answers.