# How to get the last inserted N records from mongodb using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, collections

There is an analogous post for using mongodb scripting
[mongodb: how to get the last N records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records)

How to achieve the same goal with Java getting the last inserted collection document?
Just in case, **I am using the 3rd version of the mongodb Java driver**, my mongodb dependencies in pom.xml are as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the new syntax in MongoDB version 3, therefore I could not use the suggested answer . So the working code is as follows:

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(<collectionName>);

FindIterable<Document> currentVersionDocumentIterable =   
    coll.find().sort(new Document("_id", -1)).limit(50);
```

Inside sort one needs **to insert “new Document”**

Answer (score 2):

Use .limit()

```
db.foo.find().limit(50);
```

Or if you want to sort and then get last  records then you can do

```
db.foo.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(50);  and -1 for descending.
```

Comment: Its a java code, You can try doing 
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test");  
db.collection.find().sort(new Document("x", 1)).limit(n); 

If you still face problems, you can put the code here. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @Rashit, Thank you.  What do you mean by ("x", 1), is "x" any field in the document and what is 1 here?  How to do "and -1 for descending", what is the code? By the way "db.foo.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(50)" is not compiled.

Comment: Yes x is any field. Yes just use -1 for descending in the same code format as above. Also please accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: This code is not compiled: FindIterable<Document> currentVersionDocumentIterable = coll.find();
   currentVersionDocumentIterable.sort("name", 1).limit(50);

Comment: Try doing coll.find().sort("name",1).limit(50);

Comment: I have worked with many versions, I am using the current stable release 3.0.4, but this should work for all the versions.

This is the correct format.
db.collections.find().sort(key:value).limit(int value).skip(some int value);

You can also refer to this article I found.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records

Comment: Also try this article: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/