# Get last inserted element from mongodb in GoLang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a struct like this:

```
type SavedData struct {
    ID   bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Data string
    Date time.Time
}
```

I also have my

```
collection := database.C("coll_name")
```

How do I retrieve the last inserted entry in this collection ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently mongoDB is by default sorted by insertion time according to 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records) so you can just skip the first N elements of the collection like so.

```
var myData SavedData 
dbSize, err := collection.Count()
if err != nil {
        return err
}

err = c.Find(nil).skip(dbSize-1).One(&myData)
if err != nil {
        return err
}
```

or you can search in the reverse order

```
c.Find(bson.M{ "$natural": -1 }).One(&myData)
```

Comment: which is faster ?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is 5 years old. This should work Today with mongodb driver

```
collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"$natural": -1})
```

Comment: Hi I get `unknown top level operator: $natural` if I try this. Do you reckon what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use options with mongo-driver if you want to get the latest document in the collection

```golang
import(
    ...
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

myOptions := options.FindOne()
myOptions.SetSort(bson.M{"$natural":-1})
collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{}, myOptions)
```

Comment: Tried this,
myOptions := options.FindOne() myOptions.SetSort(bson.M{"$natural":-1})
  current, err := idCollection.Find(context.TODO(), myOptions)
current becomes null