# Get last inserted element from mongodb in GoLang using FindOne and $natural

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongo-go

I'm trying to retrieve the last inserted document using FindOne as suggested elsewhere:

```
collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"$natural": -1})
```

[Get last inserted element from mongodb in GoLang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127583/get-last-inserted-element-from-mongodb-in-golang)

Here is my example:

```
    var lastrecord bson.M
if err = collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"$natural": -1}).Decode(&lastrecord); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(lastrecord)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
(BadValue) unknown top level operator: $natural
```

I'd prefer to use FindOne if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You want to sort using natural order, yet you specify it as a filter, which is what the error says.

To use `$natural` to specify sorting:

```
opts := options.FindOne().SetSort(bson.M{"$natural": -1})
var lastrecord bson.M
if err = coll.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{}, opts).Decode(&lastrecord); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(lastrecord)
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew there was an additional item I was missing but didn't know how to apply the sort to find one. Are you able to point me at some useful docs on how to construct the opts?

Comment: Options is a builder, it has methods to set any option. Check out the docs of course: https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options