# How to get the last N elements with a matching key from a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Collection of documents that looks like this:

```
[
 {
   "_id": "588cf61e5120ac11d4366f5c",
   "title": "This is a test entry",
   "entrybody": "This is the body of an entry",
   "creationdate": 1111,
   "author": "1223cllclclclc",
   "__v": 0
  },
 {
   "_id": "588cf6a556414f02f4e6a865",
   "title": "This is a new entry",
   "entrybody": "This is the body of an nuew entry",
   "creationdate": 11114040050505,
   "author": "1223cllclclclclslslsl",
   "__v": 0
 },
 {
   "_id": "588cf767fc2ede200cd5738e",
   "title": "This is a new entry",
   "entrybody": "This is the body of an nuew entry",
   "creationdate": 11114040050505,
   "author": "1223cllclclclclslslsl",
   "__v": 0
   }
  .....
]
```

I would like to get the last n records of each author and then order them by creation date, i have looked up how to do this with aggregation but im stuck.

I need the last N documents of the collection that match an especific key e.g author, and then i have to sort that result by "creation date". I think thats different from this question [mongodb: how to get the last N records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesnt answer my question, it shows how to get the last N documents of a collection but nothing related to getting the last N records that match an expecific key and then sorts that result by creation date.

Comment: You just need to include query criteria. Try `db.collection.find({"author":"somevalue"}).sort({"creationda‌​te":-1}).limit(10)`;

Comment: That would return the documents for just one author, i need the query to return last N documents for all authors.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. You need aggregation for this.

Comment: Yes, but im stuck on how to implement aggregations to get what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

`$sort` to process the records for each `author` on last `creationdate`.

`$group` and `$project` to pick last N records for each `author`.

`$unwind` and `$sort` to process records by `creationdate`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $sort: {
        author: 1,
        creationdate: -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$author",
        data: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        lastN: {
            $slice: ["$data", N]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$lastN"
}, {
    $sort: {
        "lastN.creationdate": -1
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that almost did the trick for me, i only had to sort again the resulting array of objects by creationdate with .sort() to make it work as i needed.

Comment: Np. You don't have to sort. Fixed the answer as it was missing reference. The last sort is what is need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to solve the problem with help of [forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method:

```
var result = {};
db.collection.find().sort({"author": 1, "creationda‌‌te":-1}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    if (!(doc.author in result)) { 
        result[doc.author] = [];
    }
    if (result[doc.author].length < 5) { 
        result[doc.author].push(doc); 
    } 
})
```

After execution, the `result` variable is filled with documents separated by author's name like

```
{
    'author1': [
        {doc1},
        {doc2}
    ],
    'author2': [
        {doc1},
        {doc2}
    ]
}
```