# NODE - MONGO: getting last N entry, but older to newer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

i would like to get the last N entry from a collection, but ordered oldest to newer.
If i just do:

```
.limit(N).sort({_id:-1})
```

it give me the the last N entry, but ordered from newest to oldest.
I'm not using moongoose, but the mongo driver.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a `.reverse()` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb: how to get the last N records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records)

Comment: I think that you should use `.sort()` before `.limit()` or it will `limit` the entries and then `sort` them

Comment: @zero298 not really: i started from that but indeed the order you get is reverse compared to what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) - sort in descending order, limit, then sort in ascending order:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    { $limit: N },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - N)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will order the results `DESC` by the `_id` field.

```
.limit(N).sort('-_id')
```

Answer (score -1):

Initially i had:

```
db.collection(process.env.MESSAGES_COLLECTION).find(req.queryValues).sort({_id:-1}).limit(req.limit)
```

I've tried:

```
db.collection(process.env.MESSAGES_COLLECTION).find(req.queryValues).aggregate([
                {$sort: {_id: -1}},
                { $limit: req.limit},
                {$sort: {_id: 1}}])
```

But i got an error: 
TypeError: db.collection(...).find(...).aggregate is not a function

If i try:

```
db.collection(process.env.MESSAGES_COLLECTION).aggregate([
            {$find: req.queryValues},
            {$sort: {_id: -1}},
            { $limit: req.limit},
            {$sort: {_id: 1}}])
```

I get an empty array.

Comment: had to use $match inside aggregate instead of find() outside