# Trying to use findOne query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can someone help me understand what I'm dong wrong. I'm trying to fetch the last recorded ID in my mongodb collection

```
db.collection('task').findOne(({_id: new ObjectID}).sort('_id:: -1').limit(1), (error, task) => {
        if(error){
            return console.log('There is no data inside the collection')
        }
    })
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using`{_id: new ObjectID}` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last N records in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/how-to-get-the-last-n-records-in-mongodb)

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the last recorded document in the collection by id

Comment: What do you mean by 'last record'? Are you referring to the last saved record, or the actual 'last' record (which would always return the very first saved document)?

Answer (score 0):

After constant tries I got this to work

```
db.collection('task').findOne({}, {sort: {id: -1},limit: 1}, (error, task) => {
        if(error){
            return console.log('There is no data inside the collection')
        }
        console.log(task)
    })
```