# Mongo db Collection find returns from the first entry not from last from client side

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using mongodb and i am querying the database with some conditions which are working fine but the results are coming from the first entry to last where as i want to query from the last added entry to the collection in database

```
TaggedMessages.find({taggedList:{$elemMatch:{tagName:tagObj.tagValue}}}).fetch()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last N records in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/how-to-get-the-last-n-records-in-mongodb)

Comment: not really , i tried natural

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor uses a custom wrapped version of [`Mongo.Collection`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html) and [`Mongo.Cursor`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor) in order to support reactivity out of the box. It also abstracts the Mongo query API to make it easier to work with.

This is why the [native way of accessing elements from the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/how-to-get-the-last-n-records-in-mongodb) is not working here.

### On the server

In order to use `$natural` correctly with Meteor you can to use the [`hint` property as option (see the last property in the documentation)](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) on the server:

```js
const selector = {
  taggedList:{ $elemMatch:{ tagName:tagObj.tagValue } }
}

const options = {
  hint: { $natural : -1 }
}

TaggedMessages.find(selector, options).fetch()
```

Sidenote: If you ever need to access the "native" Mongo driver, you need to use [`rawCollection`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection)

### On the client

On the client you have no real access to the Mongo Driver but to a seemingly similar API (called the `minimongo` package). There you won't have `$natural` available (maybe in the future), so you need to use sort with a descenging order:

```js
const selector = {
  taggedList:{ $elemMatch:{ tagName:tagObj.tagValue } }
}

const options = {
  sort: { createdAt: -1 }
}

TaggedMessages.find(selector, options).fetch()
```

Comment: its still querying from the first to end, not end to first

Comment: Maybe it's interfered by `$elemMatch` or you use any addittional `sort` here? Does it work if you just use the all selector `{}`?

Comment: Note, that it's server-only, as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: but sort is for both i think but that is still not working

Comment: const selector = {
                taggedList:{ $elemMatch:{ tagName:tagObj.tagValue } }
              }
              const options = {
                sort: { createdAt : 1 }
              }

Comment: it is still sorting the way it was not from the reverse

Comment: This is because `createdAt: 1` is sorting ascending. If you want to sort descending you need `createdAt: -1`

Comment: and still hint and natural is working in server side but i need to make query from client side , so i updated ur answer

Comment: hahah, did u add the same thing, sort? i too did that